# Не запускается чужое решение из JB Rider (С#) на MacOS

Tags: c#, macos, jetbrains, rider

На днях получил лабораторную работу, в которой мне нужно загрузить решение с C#-проектом и слегка модернизировать.

Изначально пользовался VS for Mac (на которой всё запускалось), но мне она не нравилась, и я нашёл более подходящую мне IDE - Rider. С ней в целом всё отлично, проблем не наблюдал, кроме одной...

---

После открытия и попытке запуска проекта в терминале получаю `Process finished with exit code 138`. В самом решении используется .NET 6. Пробовал её переустанавливать и ставить другие. Я предполагаю, что проблема заключается в том, что IDE просто не может найти и использовать нужный .NET, но не уверен.[image]
[image]

---

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить мою проблему? :(

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте такие действия:

1. в настройках проекта выбрать SDK 6, framework .net 6
2. удалить папки obj и bin
3. восстановить нугеты, если нужны и не восстановились сами. пересобрать проект (пкм по проекту)
4. запустить в режиме дебага (жук)